# Calculate mouse wheel scroll speed using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousewheel

I need some help computing and calculating mouse wheel scrolling speed.

I want to determine when the user is scrolling using their mousewheel and how fast or slow they scrolling.

Based on speed I want to do some operations.

**How can I find mousewheel scrolling speed?**

Comment: you can use `delta` for it

Comment: new Date().getTime() onmousemove and offset() onmousemove as your starting point.....get new Date().getTime() once scroll position intercepts container or element of known offset()

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob could you you please give code example of that please?

Answer (score 4):

I've looked into this before, and there are three issues here.

1. Mouse wheel speed varies in how it is reported by the browser.
2. User preferences determine what impact each 'click' of a scroll has on a site.
3. There are some mouses that don't 'click' and instead spin freely, which gives weird numbers.

The combination of these three make this a rather useless metric to do anything useful with.  One person could scroll 5 times and be at the bottom of your site, while another 30 times and only advanced one paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use `deltaY` as a value. `deltaY` could be negative(scroll top) or positive(scroll down).

Convert the value to only positive number using `Math.abs(event.deltaY)` and you can use that as a speed.